# Hidding div blocks according to an inner div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, e-commerce

I'm quite new at jQuery and I'm having troubles.

First, I will explain my problem:

We are coding a site for an online shop using OXID e-commerce. In the article list, we want to install some filters. One of them it's a price filter. We read the maximum an minimum price on the DB, store it on a cookie and let the user choose an interval where this filter gonna work. So at the beginning, all the article list is loaded.
This list look like this:

A div container with al the single products:

Inside it, we have each product in:

And, inside the product, we have another div with the price.

For each product, we have differents id's.

```
<div id="productList">
  ...
  <div id="test_cntr_1_0015-0001-2250-0186 " class="product">
    ...
    <div class="form_wrapper">
      ...
      <form>
        ...
        <div class="price">1,99 €</div>
        ...
      </form>
      ...
    </div>
  ...
  </div>
...
</div>
```

There's a form inside because you can buy a product without going into the details.

So, the point:

Once the document is ready, the user can set "the price bounds" and jQuery should hide all those products whose price is not between the bounds. The value of the bounds is read via cookies.

What I have untill now is:

```
$("#productList div.product div.price").each(function (index) {
  // What I should write here ?
}
```

Which actually is selecting one by one the divs I need, but, how can I compare the price ? I mean, access to the inner div price and check if it's between the bound, and otherwise, change the value to hidden ?

Assume we already have the values on the script.

Thanks so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand upon Natthakit Susanthitanon's answer.  I'm assuming you have validated price bound inputs -

```
<input id="upperBound" type="text">
<input id="lowerBound" type="text">
```

Then you can do this -

```
$("#productList div.product div.price").each(function (index) {
    var price = $(this).data("price-value");
    var lower = $("#lowerBound").val();
    var upper = $("#upperBound").val();
    if(price >= lower && price <= upper)
        $(this).parents(".product").show();
    else
        $(this).parents(".product").hide();
  });
```

EDIT: Just re-read your question.  How are you accessing your cookies?  If you need to access your cookies in jQuery I would recommend Klaus Hartl's plugin on Git Hub(https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Comment: Thanks to all you guys. I will work on it this morning and see how's going.

Best !

Answer (score 0):

Add data-* attributes to all your div.price, for example:

```
<div class="price" data-price-value="1.99" data-price-unit="eur">1,99 €</div>
```

then you can access by:

```
$("#productList div.product div.price").each(function (index) {
    var data = $(this).data(); // return {priceValue: 1.99, priceUnit: 'eur'} for the example div above
    // check the price range here by using data.priceValue
}
```

Comment: And, one last thing: did the data-* attributes are a standar ? Or I will have problems using this attributes ?

Thanks !

Comment: Yes, more info [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) or you can read about $.data() in jQuery docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot Natthakit ! Very helpful !